# Google's Native Client and Compiling SDL2

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl-2, google-nativeclient

I am running into an issue building an app with pepper_46 using the SDL2 libraries. I have scoured the internet and finally managed to find Google's [webports](https://chromium.googlesource.com/webports.git) which allowed me to compile SDL2 for pnacl properly.

The issue I am having now is actually compiling everything with the makefile...

Here is the bare minimum c++ file I am trying to compile that calls SDL_Init:

```
#include "ppapi/cpp/instance.h"
#include "ppapi/cpp/module.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

class firstInstance : public pp::Instance {
public:
  explicit firstInstance(PP_Instance instance) : pp::Instance(instance)  {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  }

  virtual ~firstInstance() {}
};

class firstModule : public pp::Module {
  public:
    firstModule() : pp::Module() {}
    virtual ~firstModule() {}

  virtual pp::Instance* CreateInstance(PP_Instance instance) {
    return new firstInstance(instance);
  }
};

namespace pp {
  Module* CreateModule(){
    return new firstModule();
  }
}
```

I have also made a few changes to my makefile in hopes that It would compile properly:

```
# Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.

# GNU Makefile based on shared rules provided by the Native Client SDK.
# See README.Makefiles for more details.

VALID_TOOLCHAINS := pnacl

NACL_SDK_ROOT ?= $(abspath $(CURDIR)/..)

TARGET = first

include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk

LIBS = SDLmain SDL2 ppapi_gles2 ppapi_simple ppapi_cpp nacl_io ppapi pthread

CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11
SOURCES = first.cc

# Build rules generated by macros from common.mk:

$(foreach src,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(call COMPILE_RULE,$(src),$(CFLAGS))))

# The PNaCl workflow uses both an unstripped and finalized/stripped binary.
# On NaCl, only produce a stripped binary for Release configs (not Debug).
ifneq (,$(or $(findstring pnacl,$(TOOLCHAIN)),$(findstring Release,$(CONFIG))))
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
$(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped))
else
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
endif

$(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET)))
```

But the best I get is this error:

```
bobkingof12vs$ make serve
  CXX  pnacl/Release/first.o
  LINK pnacl/Release/first_unstripped.bc
/nacl/pepper_46/lib/pnacl/Release/libppapi_simple.a: error: undefined reference to 'PSUserMainGet'
make: *** [pnacl/Release/first_unstripped.bc] Error 1
```

I read a post that suggested that someone fixed a similar issue with an `ldflag` of `-Wl,--undefined=PSUserMainGet`... but I can't figure out how to add that properly to the makefile... if that is even the right fix. I also saw that their `LIBS` are in the wrong order... and putting `SDL2` and `ppapi_simple` in the list twice worked for someone else. They were all old posts though and nothing I tried worked (not that I necessarily tried it correctly)

I am terribly lost... Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a few sources that helped me finally figure it out...

So, after doing the webports deal to get SDL installed correctly, I continued my hunt for the correct makefile to use.

Finally found one on gituhub: https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/blob/master/test/nacl/Makefile (it looks a lot different than the normal nacl makefile!)

With a description of what to do here: https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/blob/master/docs/README-nacl.md

The only other thing I needed to do was add this function to my c++ code:

```
int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  return 0;
}
```

My code now compiles to say the least! Crashes instantly, but compiles!

I will post more if I find something missing that helps

Comment: I still getting the same error. I am using pepper version is 47. libppapi_simple.a: error: undefined reference to 'PSUserMainGet'

Comment: I know this was half a year ago, but did you get it working correctly? If so, it would be very helpful to know what you did.

Comment: Sorry, these are the only notes I have and haven't worked with it since this post.